# Solve the reccurence relation for $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n − 1, n > 1, T(1) = 0, n = 2^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Even though it's pretty similar to other questions, I'm confusing myself with the answer because I always end up with:

$$
T(2^k)=\log_2⁡n-\log_2⁡n
$$

which doesn't seem right at all. Plus, I'm not sure whether the final big theta notation would be $\Theta(\log_2⁡n)$ or $\Theta(1)$.

I don't know what else to do. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here's the obvious extremely wrong attempt:
\begin{align*}
A(2^k )&=2A(2^{k-1} )+2^k-1\\
&=(2A(2^{k-2} )+2^k-1)+2^k-1
&&=2A(2^{k-2} )+2(2^k)-2\\
&=(2A(2^{k-3} )+2^k-1)+2(2^k)-2
&&=2A(2^{k-3} )+3(2^k)-3
\end{align*}
$$
A(2^k)=2A(2^{k-i} )+i(2^k)-i
$$
sub in $i = k$:
\begin{align*}
A(2^k)&=2A(2^{k-k} )+k(2^k)-k  \\
&=2A(2^0 )+k(2^k)-k &&  \\
&=\log_2⁡n-\log_2⁡n\\
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you end up with that answer? You should show us how you have tried to solve this problem, so perhaps someone will be able to identify your mistake.

Comment: Let $R(k)=T(2^k)$ then $$R(0)=0, R(k)=R(k-1)+2^{k}-1.$$ I also don't see how you got your formula.

Comment: @koblieguap I think it would be better to include your attempt in the question. You can edit your question and copy-paste your attempt there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more careful about your substitutions and expanding. Observe that:
\begin{align*}
A(2^k)
&= 2A(2^{k-1}) + 2^k - 1 = 2 [ 2A(2^{k-2}) + 2^{k-1} - 1] + 2^k - 1 \\
&= 2^2A(2^{k-2}) + 2(2^k) - (1 + 2) = 2^2[ 2A(2^{k-3}) + 2^{k-2} - 1] + 2(2^k) - (1 + 2) \\
&= 2^3A(2^{k-3}) + 3(2^k) - (1 + 2 + 2^2) = 2^3[ 2A(2^{k-4}) + 2^{k-3} - 1] + 3(2^k) - (1 + 2 + 2^2) \\
&= 2^4A(2^{k-4}) + 4(2^k) - (1 + 2 + 2^2 + 2^3)
\end{align*}

Do you see the pattern? Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote
$$\color{red}{2A(2^{k-1} )}+2^k-1=\color{red}{(2A(2^{k-2} )+2^k-1)}+2^k-1.$$
But you seem to assume $2A(2^{k-1}) = 2A(2^{k-2}) + 2^k - 1$, which is incorrect.

It should be
\begin{align*}
2 \cdot A(2^{k-1}) &= 2 \cdot (2A(2^{k-2}) + 2^{k-1} - 1) \\
&= 4A(2^{k-2}) + 2^k - 2.
\end{align*}